# Do randomized quicksort runs faster than tail recursion quick sort?

Tags: arrays, go, recursion, quicksort

I have implemented both randomized quicksort and tail recursion quicksort in golang and logged the running time. I found out that tail recursion quicksort is taking more time to sort the array. My input length of the arrays are 250, 500, 750, 1000, 1250, 1500, 1750, 2000, 2250, 2500.

Below's are my golang code implementions.

**Randomized Quicksort:**

```css
// this method will sort the array and place pivot at than correct position.
// we will then run another randomizedquicksort on the partitioned array.
// It take both float and int arrays as input
func randomizedquicksort(arr []interface{}, left int, right int) {
    if left < right {
        pivot := randomizedPartition(arr, left, right)
        randomizedquicksort(arr, left, pivot-1)
        randomizedquicksort(arr, pivot+1, right)
    }
}

func partition(a []interface{}, left int, right int) int {
    pivot := a[right]
    i := left - 1
    for j := left; j <= right-1; j++ {
        switch piv := pivot.(type) {
        case float64:
            if a[j].(float64) < piv {
                i++
                //swap
                a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i]
            }
        case int:
            if a[j].(int) < piv {
                i++
                //swap
                a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i]
            }
        }
    }
    //swap pivot with pth index
    a[right], a[i+1] = a[i+1], a[right]
    return i + 1
}
```

**Tail Recursion Quicksort:**

```css
// this method will sort the array and place pivot at than correct position.
// we will then run another quicksort on the partitioned array.
// Last thing we do is recursion in tail recursion
func tailRecursivequicksort(a []interface{}, left int, right int) {
    for left < right {
        pi := tailPartition(a, left, right)
        tailRecursivequicksort(a, left, right-1)
        left = pi + 1
    }
}

// this method will partition the array around pivot and return pivot's index
func tailPartition(a []interface{}, left int, right int) int {
    pivot := a[right]
    p := left - 1
    for i := left; i < right; i++ {
        switch piv := pivot.(type) {
        case float64:
            // if element is found lower than pivot swap it with pth element
            if a[i].(float64) <= piv {
                //swap
                p++
                a[p], a[i] = a[i], a[p]
            }
        case int:
            // if element is found lower than pivot swap it with pth element
            if a[i].(int) <= piv {
                //swap
                p++
                a[p], a[i] = a[i], a[p]
            }
        }
    }
    //swap pivot with pth index
    a[right], a[p+1] = a[p+1], a[right]
    return p + 1
}
```

One sample unit test cases for tail recursion quicksort:

```css
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "testing"
    "time"
)

// 250 numbers
func TestTailRecursionQuickSort1(t *testing.T) {
    startTime := time.Now()
    actualArray := []interface{}{123, 39, 2, 198, 236, 5, 214, 195, 100, 86, 162, 16, 233, 34, 197, 209, 173, 174, 238, 75, 6, 12, 191, 4, 44, 108, 85, 72, 216, 210, 248, 152, 226, 155, 38, 103, 45, 136, 206, 19, 181, 107, 81, 133, 118, 35, 190, 154, 212, 193, 232, 106, 196, 43, 243, 63, 245, 165, 60, 124, 36, 235, 137, 176, 228, 234, 183, 22, 187, 128, 142, 42, 29, 224, 131, 112, 110, 117, 217, 98, 178, 13, 74, 146, 122, 109, 1, 121, 78, 229, 46, 127, 150, 114, 28, 95, 8, 237, 32, 207, 166, 227, 144, 120, 15, 17, 94, 151, 47, 88, 247, 192, 82, 230, 31, 41, 138, 56, 21, 97, 53, 164, 126, 30, 67, 91, 66, 105, 71, 148, 125, 10, 218, 99, 203, 25, 119, 40, 250, 246, 153, 51, 84, 102, 186, 33, 37, 93, 104, 68, 18, 50, 139, 80, 205, 199, 20, 57, 27, 249, 145, 223, 168, 83, 140, 90, 201, 23, 184, 221, 156, 163, 202, 204, 157, 175, 241, 219, 116, 54, 149, 129, 194, 49, 64, 167, 211, 62, 87, 89, 59, 169, 14, 244, 200, 79, 24, 141, 171, 77, 189, 147, 134, 180, 225, 185, 73, 111, 213, 215, 158, 52, 69, 70, 11, 135, 7, 115, 101, 177, 76, 61, 208, 242, 48, 132, 26, 188, 182, 92, 239, 3, 58, 9, 172, 113, 160, 220, 222, 143, 130, 65, 170, 240, 231, 55, 159, 96, 179, 161}
    expectedArray := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250}
    tailRecursivequicksort(actualArray, 0, 249)
    timeDiff := time.Now().Sub(startTime)
    fmt.Printf("Time take to sort %v numbers is %v", len(actualArray), timeDiff)
    for i := 0; i < len(actualArray); i++ {
        if actualArray[i] != expectedArray[i] {
            t.Fail()
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Running time logs:

```
=== RUN   TestRandomizedQuickSort1
Time take to sort 250 numbers is 93.1µs--- PASS: TestRandomizedQuickSort1 (0.00s)
=== RUN   TestRandomizedQuickSort2
Time take to sort 500 numbers is 153.913µs--- PASS: TestRandomizedQuickSort2 (0.00s)
=== RUN   TestRandomizedQuickSort3
Time take to sort 750 numbers is 249.653µs--- PASS: TestRandomizedQuickSort3 (0.00s)
=== RUN   TestRandomizedQuickSort4
Time take to sort 1000 numbers is 299.693µs--- PASS: TestRandomizedQuickSort4 (0.00s)
=== RUN   TestRandomizedQuickSort5
Time take to sort 1250 numbers is 452.812µs--- PASS: TestRandomizedQuickSort5 (0.00s)
=== RUN   TestRandomizedQuickSort6
Time take to sort 1500 numbers is 577.646µs--- PASS: TestRandomizedQuickSort6 (0.00s)
=== RUN   TestRandomizedQuickSort7
Time take to sort 1750 numbers is 793.466µs--- PASS: TestRandomizedQuickSort7 (0.00s)
=== RUN   TestRandomizedQuickSort8
Time take to sort 2000 numbers is 2.100078ms--- PASS: TestRandomizedQuickSort8 (0.00s)
=== RUN   TestRandomizedQuickSort9
Time take to sort 2250 numbers is 1.534166ms--- PASS: TestRandomizedQuickSort9 (0.00s)
=== RUN   TestRandomizedQuickSort10
Time take to sort 2500 numbers is 1.488542ms--- PASS: TestRandomizedQuickSort10 (0.00s)
PASS

Debugger finished with the exit code 0




=== RUN   TestTailRecursionQuickSort1
Time take to sort 250 numbers is 2.166925ms--- PASS: TestTailRecursionQuickSort1 (0.00s)
=== RUN   TestTailRecursionQuickSort2
Time take to sort 500 numbers is 11.049337ms--- PASS: TestTailRecursionQuickSort2 (0.01s)
=== RUN   TestTailRecursionQuickSort3
Time take to sort 750 numbers is 36.98923ms--- PASS: TestTailRecursionQuickSort3 (0.04s)
=== RUN   TestTailRecursionQuickSort4
Time take to sort 1000 numbers is 213.94526ms--- PASS: TestTailRecursionQuickSort4 (0.21s)
=== RUN   TestTailRecursionQuickSort5
Time take to sort 1250 numbers is 87.065747ms--- PASS: TestTailRecursionQuickSort5 (0.09s)
=== RUN   TestTailRecursionQuickSort6
Time take to sort 1500 numbers is 105.232837ms--- PASS: TestTailRecursionQuickSort6 (0.11s)
PASS

Debugger finished with the exit code 0
=== RUN   TestTailRecursionQuickSort7
Time take to sort 1750 numbers is 2.632979054s--- PASS: TestTailRecursionQuickSort7 (2.63s)
=== RUN   TestTailRecursionQuickSort8
Time take to sort 2000 numbers is 1.082278134s--- PASS: TestTailRecursionQuickSort8 (1.08s)
=== RUN   TestTailRecursionQuickSort9
Time take to sort 2250 numbers is 3.14799009s--- PASS: TestTailRecursionQuickSort9 (3.15s)
=== RUN   TestTailRecursionQuickSort10
Time take to sort 2500 numbers is 4.877045862s--- PASS: TestTailRecursionQuickSort10 (4.88s)
```

After running the test cases for both the algorithms, I found that randomized quick sort is faster that tail recursion. Isn't tail recursion is the optimization of the randomized quicksort? Let me know your thoughts.

Thanks

Comment: I don't believe Go implements TRO (Tail Recursion Optimization): every recursive call is allocating a new stack frame.

Comment: Tail recursion is used to reduce stack space usage, not time.

Comment: @rcgldr: Well, primarily - it usually makes it faster as well. --- This question seems to me as an apples to oranges comparison, though: random pivot selection (or not) and tail recursion elimination (or not) can each be applied (or not) independently.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError - lost an edit on my comment, it can be a bit faster, assuming compiler optimizes true tail recursion into a loop, but converting the code to use a loop will work even if the compiler doesn't do the optimization. Recursing on the smaller partition first and looping back on the larger partition will limit stack space to O(log(n)).

Answer (score 0):

The question's code does not include random partition function. The tail recursion is only reducing size by one on each loop (from right to right-1) a worst case scenario. The Lomuto partition scheme used in the code degrades to worst case time complexity if there are a lot of repeated elements:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Repeated_elements

Example C++ Hoare partition code that recurses on smaller partition, then loops back for the larger partition.

```
void QuickSort(int a[], int lo, int hi)
{
    while (lo < hi){
        int p = a[lo + (hi - lo) / 2];
        int i = lo - 1;
        int j = hi + 1;
        while (1){
            while (a[++i] < p);
            while (a[--j] > p);
            if (i >= j)
                break;
            std::swap(a[i], a[j]);
        }
        if(j - lo < hi - j){
            QuickSort(a, lo, j);
            lo = j+1;
        } else {
            QuickSort(a, j+1, hi);
            hi = j;
        }
    }
}
```

A true C++ tail recursion example. Visual Studio release build will convert the tail recursion calls into loops.

```
void QuickSort(int a[], int lo, int hi)
{
    if(lo < hi){
        int p = a[lo + (hi - lo) / 2];
        int i = lo - 1;
        int j = hi + 1;
        while (1){
            while (a[++i] < p);
            while (a[--j] > p);
            if (i >= j)
                break;
            std::swap(a[i], a[j]);
        }
        if(j - lo < hi - j){
            QuickSort(a, lo, j);
            QuickSort(a, j+1, hi);  // converted to loop
        } else {
            QuickSort(a, j+1, hi);
            QuickSort(a, lo, j);    // converted to loop
        }
    }
}
```